# Can the Force be used to stop/reduce aging?

Tags: star-wars

I know very little about Star Wars, but I'm curious how powerful the Force truly is.

Comment: You may want to flesh out this question a little more to explain what you're asking and to include the title question inside the question itself.

Comment: Did you ever hear the tragedy of Darth Plagueis The Wise?

Comment: @ArthurDent - The now-legends book by the same name, *Darth Plagueis*, is a great read and major plot line of the book (cheating aging). The Darth Bane trilogy also touches on this topic as Bane finds a holocron (forgot whose) that tells the secrets of essence transfer where one can transfer his being/soul into someone else, prolonging life indefinitely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. There is at least [one example](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sith_Emperor) of a Force-user prolonging their life by thousands of years using the Force. It is also theorised, by Winter and Luke Skywalker, that Jedi would be capable of using the Force to slow the ageing process in *Dark Force Rising*. Palpatine, Yoda, and C'Baoth were the object of their discussion; C'Baoth was well over 100 years old by that point, despite being human (as it turned out, the C'Baoth in question was a clone, so the discussion was moot).

There are also [other beings](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Abeloth) who achieved extremely long life-spans through the use of the Force, though this may have been a natural part of their existence, rather than through any Force-related assistance. There were multiple attempts, mostly by Dark-Siders, to achieve [immortality](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Immortality) through the Force.

Comment: I could be wrong, but wasn't Mace Windu actually in his 70s or so? I thought it was established in one of the comics that Windu was much older than he appeared for this very reason. At work now, so can't really do the needed research though.

Comment: @Omegacron: Born 72BBY, died 19BBY. Makes him 53.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

In Disney canon, Darth Sidious plotted to use the power of the dark side to rule for ten thousand years:

> Such perilous machinations required two Sith, one to serve as bait for
> the dark side, the other to be the vessel. Success would grant them
> the power to harness the full powers of the dark side, and allow them
> to rule for ten thousand years.
>
> <sub>*Tarkin*</sub>

Biotechnology in *Star Wars* has not yet advanced to the point at which humans can live for ten millenia, so I think we can safely say that Sidious was planning to use the dark side to attain immortality, as well as ultimate power.

Answer (score -1):

There was a Sith Lord that couldn't be killed, Darth Sion, during the Old Republic (around 2800 BBY). He ressurected multiple times and surpised and killed a lot of jedi. His power was gained through meditation and chaneling his hate towards the jedi. The darkside consumed him, tuning him into a corpse (held together by the dark side of the Force), and caused him constant huge pain, used to fuel his power. In the end he decided to give up his hate and allowed some jedi to kill him.
It's somehow similar to the way in which Darth Maul survived the first duel with Obi Wan, by focusing his hate.
So, yeah, sith could potentially live forever only by deeply hating Jedi Order.

Comment: Which Sith lord is that? Your answer would greatly benefit from some references.

Comment: Even if what you say is true (= verifiable), I’m not sure it answers the question.  One can’t be resurrected unless he’s died, so how can you justify a claim that this character has stopped/reduced aging?

Comment: The Sith was Darth Sion, one of the members of the Sith Triumvirate, along with Darth Traya and Darth Nihilus.

Comment: After his first ressurection, Sion stopped aging. He was a living corpse. The only ones who tried to stop aging were Sith Lords. We all know that the dark side literally consumed an individual's body (Darth Sidious in "Revenge of the Sith", the duel with Windu). Sith magic was dangerous. The try itself to reduce aging aged phisically the practitioner.