# Did Palpatine gain any new Force powers as Emperor?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, darth-sidious

Palpatine ruled something like 23 years as emperor of the Galactic Empire. He has claimed he wants to ["harness the full powers of the Dark Side"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141878/did-the-emperor-intend-to-live-forever-if-so-how). But did he actually learn anything useful that he didn't know as a Chancellor?

I'm mostly interested in Canon, I know that in Legends he could be [reborn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Palpatine) and create [Force storms](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_storm_(wormhole)). But in Canon, his powers are mostly stagnant except the little adventure with the [Lothal Temple](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lothal_Jedi_Temple) and time travel. Am I missing something?

Comment: Having a fully armed and operational battle station isn't a a force power? Darn it, now how will it get my own Death Star?

Comment: @Xantec Actually ... https://www.inverse.com/article/22467-death-star-plans-catalyst-rogue-one-dooku

Answer (score 2):

From the [Star Wars Wikia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Sidious):

> After the creation of his Sith Empire, Palpatine established himself
>   in the old Jedi Temple on Coruscant, transforming it into the Imperial
>   Palace. The Jedi had built the palace atop an ancient Sith shrine,
>   **in order to neutralize and cap the dark power that sprang from its depths**.
>
> During his rule, Sidious sent explorers to unmapped regions of the
>   galaxy to **search for the source of the dark side**, believing it lay
>   there.

A reasonable hypothesis could be that Sidious was more interested in finding and harvesting the raw power source of the Dark Side than in developing additional skills - or perhaps that the increase in power would infer the gaining of new skills.