# Is there really a zombie infested ship in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

There is a detailed and large chunk of lore supporting the idea that somewhere within the Star Wars universe there is a ship containing a virus that turns living things into "zombies" and what I would like to know is whether or not this is true.

Comment: “somewhere living in the Star Wars universe” — not sure the word “living” is exactly right here. “There is a detailed and large chunk of lore” — there is? Could you link to it?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the word "living" I replaced it with the word within. The site that I found that can somewhat answer my question is found here http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_bioweapons_Project_I71A

Comment: Additionally to the answer given there is the fact that geonosian larvas can create pseudo zombies by "infesting" them with themselves.....the question excludes them as it was asked about a ship (and it is the one in the answer) but for completeness sake mentioned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may be referring to [Project Blackwing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Project_Blackwing):

> The virus was accidentally created while working on an experiment to
>   revive necrotic tissue, however, killed its hosts instead, attacking
>   their biological tissue and turning their lifeless bodies into
>   cannibalistic, brutal zombies.

This was described in the novel *Death Troopers* and included in the *Star Wars: Commander* mobile strategy game.  Wikia suggests the latter makes it part of canon.

This [news release from starwars.com](https://www.starwars.com/news/death-troopers-invade-star-wars-commander-exclusive) makes it sound like much like a *Call of Duty* style "Nazi Zombies" <del>rip</del>variant.

This information is referenced in [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/141881/20490) on this site which can be found by searching for "[star-wars] zombies".

Answer (score 2):

In Star Wars: The Clone Wars, there was an episode where Barriss Offee and Ahsoka Tano are on board a ship with Tango Company (Clones). Brain worms are on board the ship, and they take over the bodies of the Clones, with the plan to eventually kill the Jedi. They fail to cover their tracks, and they are stopped. I don't remember if this happened in this episode, but at one point Barriss Offee got controlled by a brain worm, and attempted to kill Ahsoka herself. This failed, however, because the worms couldn't survive in cold temperatures (I don't remember where this came from, maybe that show). Hope that answered your question even more.