# Did Darth Vader plan on using "zombies"?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

Somewhere within the *Star Wars* universe there are "zombies" that originated from Project Blackwing.  In *Revenge of the Sith* it shows Emperor Palpatine and Vader speaking on the subject of keeping loved ones from dying. My question is whether Darth Vader planned on using Project Blackwing, and if so, did he end up using it?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Project_Blackwing

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/202195/is-there-really-a-zombie-infested-ship-in-star-wars/202196#202196 Relevant link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Darth Vader commissioned Project Blackwing in order to use it as a weapon. The incidents on the Star Destroyer *Vector* and the prison barge *Purge* put an end to the project.

For a detailed description and history of the origins of this project, here is [an excellent article on Wookieepedia.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Imperial_bioweapons_Project_I71A)